# Configuring visual subversion to exclude

Tags: svn, xcode

I have been searching for any documentation on how to exclude files for visual svn but have not found any. All the documentation I find seems to not match my file structure or I am missing some files/directories referenced. For example the only file I find with configuration items in it seems to be completely commented out and missing the miscellaneous section as well as any auto properties enable - etc...

Ultimately I need to exclude some files so that my development can continue without SVN errors. I am constantly receiving errors for pbuser and other project files and would like to make sure this is not causing some of my other headaches.

[Here is information I would love to use](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/how-to-fix-subversion-in-xcode-3.html) but cant as it doesnt match:

```
How to “fix” Subversion in XCode 3
Posted on December 10, 2008 by Rodney Aiglstorfer in Xcode 

If you don’t take the necessary steps to prepare for subversion, you will run into
problems using it in XCode. This is because XCode produces files that “confuse”
Subversion because it either thinks they are text files when they are really binary
files or the reverse. To overcome these limitations, you need to make some simple
changes to the subversion configuration file in your user home directory. Here are
some steps you can follow to ensure that you will be able to use Subversion within
XCode without any issues.

Step 1. Open the subversion configuration file

~/.subversion/config
NOTE: If the “.subversion” directory doesn’t exist yet then run this command which
fails but will create the necessary files to get you started:

svn status
Step 2. Enable “global-ignores” and add new things to ignore

Find the line that contains the text “global-ignores” and append the following text:

build *~.nib *.so *.pbxuser *.mode* *.perspective*
```

What I am looking for really is how to exclude the files I know I need to for Visual subversion - it shouldnt be different really from regular svn as it claims to use the same product just places a gui on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have figured this out. It appears that lacking in any of the subversion documentation is that this is done on the client level not on the server. I was under the impression I was looking for a config on the server to exclude these files from the server processing.

so simply:
 open terminal prompt on the mac
 cd ~/.subversion/
 open config
 make edits as detailed in the initial article above.
 save the config 
 close xcode and reopen